# How to create dummy variables?

Tags: r

I have a variable that is a factor :

```
 $ year           : Factor w/ 8 levels "2003","2004",..: 4 6 4 2 4 1 3 3 7 2 ...
```

I would like to create 8 dummy variables, named "2003", "2004" etc that take the value 0 or 1 depending on the value that the variable "year" takes. The nearest I could come up with is

```
dt1 <- cbind (dt1, model.matrix(~dt1$year - 1) )
```

But this has the unfortunate consequences of

1. The dummy variables are named dt1$year2003, not just "2003", "2004" etc
2. It seems that NA rows are omitted altogether by `model.matrix` (so the above command fails due to different lengths when NA is present in the `year` variable).

Of course I can get around these problems with more code, but I like my code to be as concise as possible (within reason) so if anyone can suggest better ways to make the dummy variables I would be obliged.

Comment: I don't think you can have variable names that start with a number in `R`: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't create a dummy yourself, but use a variable of class 'factor' in a model, whereupon the function that fits the model will construct the model matrix from the factor. If you need them you can then extract the dummies from the model matrix.

Comment: @Glen_b thank you - that is useful information, so that means I can run a model such as `glmer(y~x + (year + 1|school)....` where year instead of coding dummy variables and running `glmer(y~x + (y1+y2+y3+y4+y5+y6+y7+y8 + 1|school)....` and get the same output ?

Comment: @JoeKing The examples in the help on glmer include such factors, yes

Comment: @JoeKing or at least so it appears

Comment: Treatment contrasts are the default for categorial variables in R.

Comment: @smillig: In R, You can have variable names beginning with numbers and underscores, but they should be quoted appropriately.

Comment: @Sathish Interesting. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @smillig: > `1` <- 1:5;
> `1`;
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
> `_a` <- 2:6;
> `_a`
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @smillig: As you can see, in my comment, for some reason, I could not make the variable names inside back quotes, but you can add back quotes for variable names 1 and _a

Comment: @Sathish I see what you're saying, but doesn't that technically mean that the variable name starts with a quotation mark?

Comment: @smillig: Yes, you are right, thats how you come around the variable names that begins with numeric or some special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as concise as I could get. The `na.action` option takes care of the `NA` values (I would rather do this with an argument than with a global options setting, but I can't see how). The naming of columns is pretty deeply hard-coded, don't see any way to override it within `model.matrix` ...

```
options(na.action=na.pass)
dt1 <- data.frame(year=factor(c(NA,2003:2005)))
dt2 <- setNames(cbind(dt1,model.matrix(~year-1,data=dt1)),
              c("year",levels(dt1$year)))
```

As pointed out above, you may run into trouble in some contexts with column names that are not legal R variable names.

```
  year 2003 2004 2005
1 <NA>   NA   NA   NA
2 2003    1    0    0
3 2004    0    1    0
4 2005    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifelse()` which won't omit `na` rows (but I guess you might not count it as being "as concise as possible"):

```
dt1 <- data.frame(year=factor(rep(2003:2010, 10)))  # example data

dt1 <- within(dt1, yr2003<-ifelse(year=="2003", 1, 0))
dt1 <- within(dt1, yr2004<-ifelse(year=="2004", 1, 0))
dt1 <- within(dt1, yr2005<-ifelse(year=="2005", 1, 0))
# ...    

head(dt1)
#   year yr2003 yr2004 yr2005
# 1 2003      1      0      0
# 2 2004      0      1      0
# 3 2005      0      0      1
# 4 2006      0      0      0
# 5 2007      0      0      0
# 6 2008      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

`library(caret)`  provides a very simple function (`dummyVars`)  to create dummy variables, especially when you have more than one factor variables. But you have to make sure the target variables are factor. e.g. if your `Sales$year` are numeric, you have to convert them to factor: `as.factor(Sales$year)`

Suppose we have the original dataset 'Sales' as follows:

```
    year    Sales       Region
1   2010    3695.543    North
2   2010    9873.037    West
3   2008    3579.458    West
4   2005    2788.857    North
5   2005    2952.183    North
6   2008    7255.337    West
7   2005    5237.081    West
8   2010    8987.096    North
9   2008    5545.343    North
10  2008    1809.446    West
```

Now we can create two dummy variables simultaneously:

```
>library(lattice)
>library(ggplot2)
>library(caret)
>Salesdummy <- dummyVars(~., data = Sales, levelsOnly = TRUE)
>Sdummy <- predict(Salesdummy, Sales)
```

The outcome will be:

```
   2005 2008 2010   Sales    RegionNorth    RegionWest
1   0    0    1   3695.543       1              0
2   0    0    1   9873.037       0              1
3   0    1    0   3579.458       0              1
4   1    0    0   2788.857       1              0
5   1    0    0   2952.183       1              0
6   0    1    0   7255.337       0              1
7   1    0    0   5237.081       0              1
8   0    0    1   8987.096       1              0
9   0    1    0   5545.343       1              0 
10  0    1    0   1809.446       0              1
```