# Training Neural Network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, classification, training-data

I am attempting to train a neural network but got this message. Can you tell me why? Is it because it should be numeric? I have a question mark if there is missing data. Should I change this?

```
> dataset <- read.csv("~/DATA630/ucidatasethouse-votes-84.data.csv")
> trainset <- dataset[1:305, ]
> testset <- dataset[306:435, ]
> polpartynet <- neuralnet(Party ~ HndcpInfants + WaterProject + AdoptBudget + DocFeeFreeze + ElSalvadorAid + ReligiousGroupsSchools + AntiSatellTestBan + AidNicaraguaContras + MXMissile + Immigration + SynCorpCutback + EducationSpending + SuperfundRighttoSue + Crime + DutyFreeExports + ExportAdminSouthAfrica, trainset, hidden = 4, lifesign = "minimal", linear.output = FALSE, threshold = 0.1)
hidden: 4    thresh: 0.1    rep: 1/1    steps: 
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

This is what some of my data looks like....Party is the first column(numeric) and ExportAdminSouthAfrica is the last column.

```
Party   HndcpInfants    WaterProject    AdoptBudget DocFeeFreeze    ElSalvadorAid   ReligiousGroupsSchools  AntiSatellTestBan   AidNicaraguaContras MXMissile   Immigration SynCorpCutback  EducationSpending   SuperfundRighttoSue Crime   DutyFreeExports ExportAdminSouthAfrica
1   n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   n   y
1   n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   y   n   ?
2   ?   y   y   ?   y   y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   y   n   n
2   n   y   y   n   ?   y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   n   n   y
2   y   y   y   n   y   y   n   n   n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   y
2   n   y   y   n   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   y   y
2   n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   n   ?   y   y   y
1   n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   ?   y
1   n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   y   n   y
```

Comment: What is the class of your variables? I guess you have likely already thought of this, but it may also be worth considering if a different model isn't more appropriate.

Comment: I 'm still learning terms. Class? All my variables are Factors. Does this matter? Should I change the question mark?                                                                                                          > d <- read.csv("~/DATA630/ucidatasethouse-votes-84.data.csv")
> str(d)
'data.frame': 435 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Party                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "democrat","republican": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ HndcpInfants          : Factor w/ 3 levels "?","n","y": 2 2 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 
 $ WaterProject          : Factor w/ 3 levels "?","n","y": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

Comment: Neural network naturally works with numeric variables. Of course, you can one-hot-encode factor variables and proceed. But since _all_ your variables are factors, _why_ do you want neural network in the first place?

Comment: The way to do this is turning them factors binary dummy variables, where each level of the factor is a separate column. The best way to do this is with model.matrix, as detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384506/create-new-dummy-variable-columns-from-categorical-variable). Alternatively, you can use the dummyVars function from the package caret, [detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758075/how-to-create-dummy-variables).

Comment: It's a class assignment. I will switch the n, y, ? to 1, 2, 3 and the party  to -1 and 0. How does that sound? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: This  is the latest message that I'm receiving. Please help.                        > polparty <- neuralnet(Party ~ HandInfants + WaterProject + AdoptBudget + DocFeeFreeze + ElSalvadorAid + ReligiousGroupsSchools + AntiSatellTestBan + AidNicaraguaContas + MXMissile + Immigration + SynCorpCutback + EducationSpending + SuperfundRighttoSue + Crime + DutyFreeExports + ExportAdminSouthAfrica, trainset, hidden = 4, lifesign = "minimal", linear.output = FALSE, threshold = 0.1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'HandInfants' not found