# How to create logical variables out of multilevel factor in R

Tags: r

I want to create logical variables for every level of factor `x`.

so from a factor `x <- factor(c('apple','orange','apple','peach'))` I would get three variables each the length of `x`:

```
apple = c(T,F,T,F)
orange = c(F,T,F,F)
peach = c(F,F,F,T)
```

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to create dummy variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12758075/903061).

Comment: Better possible dupe: [Generate a dummy variable in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11952706/903061).

Comment: ... from which I would recommend `model.matrix(~ x + 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It creates a data frame of those vectors:

```
x <- as.factor(c('apple','orange','apple','peach'))
df <- data.frame(sapply(levels(x), function(l) l == x))
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, but would you explain what the `function(l) l==x` does? Oh I get it... so simple...

Comment: sapply will iterative take each level of the factor from levels(x), passes each to the function where l is one of the levels. Then, l == x is checking which of the x values match the single level passed l. This operation will return a true/false vector for that single level.

Comment: You can try out by simply doing 'apple' == x to see.