# Changing a variable into a factor variable

Tags: r, factors

I have a variable (year) which is all 2007 and 2008s but I need to change it into a factor so it reads 0 and 1s. Is there a way to do this?

So it can be used in a general linear model

Comment: please take a look at the help page `?factor`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dummy variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758075/how-to-create-dummy-variables)

Comment: @NelsonGon sorry this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Ok, edit your question as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does `df$year <- ifelse(df$year == 2008, 1, 0)` well for you.

Comment: @Sonny thanks you very much, just so i know.. how do i undo this command?

Comment: You could store the 1/0 in a different column if you want `year` column to exist as it is

Comment: @Sonny i need to run some diagnostic tests on the year data so is there a way of briefly changing it back to 2007s and 2008s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only two years in your `year` variable, for example: `c(2007, 2007, 2008, 2007, 2008)`, then:

`year_as_factor <- factor(year, labels = c(0, 1))`

will give you a vector of factors with values of 0 where `year` has 2007 and 1 where `year` has 2008.

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you very much for this. Very useful. How do I recode it so it returns back to the way it was.

Comment: Alex, you can use `levels(year_as_factor) <- c(2007, 2008)` to change back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to change the levels to use it as input into a glm model, casting it as a factor using `factor(year)` would be sufficient. If, however, you still want to change the levels you can do so as per the answer below. In general you can change the levels of a factor variable via a statement such as

```
levels(year) <- c(...)
```

where `c(...)` contains the new factor levels.